# R loop over multiple matrices

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I have 472 matrices with 405 columns each (matrix1 , ... , matrix400) and want to have 472 new matrices with only the first 244 columns of that matrix. How can I do that? I tried:

```
for (i in 1:472) {
assign(paste("new_matrix",i,sep=""), matrix[[i]][,c(1:244)])
}
```

I created the matrices by splitting one dataframe by one identifier (for the groups):

```
for (i in 1:472){
   assign(paste("matrix", i, sep=""), subset(data, ID==i))
}
```

Somehow I cannot speak to each matrix but I have no clue how I can do that.

Comment: I cannot completely understand your question. Do you have all those matrix in a list?

Comment: No, they are single matrices, but their names are matrix1, matrix2, matrix3, etc.. Does this help?

Comment: Well, if you don't have a list, you should. Having a bunch of single variable names like that is just inefficient in R, especially when you want to perform similar operations on them all. You should rarely need to use `get()/assign()` in R especially if you are new to R. That's usually a sign you are not doing things "the R way". How did you create all these variables?

Comment: It is strange to have all those matrix in such a non organised way. This is the true problem. After, it is possible to found workarounds...

Comment: please see how I got these matrices, thanks already for the great support!

Comment: Where are these matrices? Hopefully they're in a `list`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You clearly should take a different approach. Assigning all of the individual
matricies is **NOT** a good approach. But here is one way you could do that...

```
mat1 <- matrix(1:6, 2, 3)
mat2 <- matrix(2:7, 2, 3)

example_func <- function(mati) {

  mat_name <- as.name(paste0("mat", mati))
  bquote(.(mat_name) <- .(mat_name)[ , 1:2])

}

for (i in 1:2) eval(example_func(i))
```

However, using `eval` can complicated because you have to be very careful about environments, especially if used within functions. As an example try running `lapply(1:2, function(x) eval(example_func(x)))` instead of using the for-loop and look at how the results differ.

### To take a better approach, look at `?split`.

```
some_data <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:4, each = 4),
                        V1 = 1:16,
                        v2 = letters[1:16])

split(some_data, list(some_data$ID))
```

Then you could use `lapply` to iterate through your subsets and subset further. Or, better yet, just subset the original data.frame down to the columns you want first, then use `split`.

Answer (score 1):

```
matrix1 <- matrix(1:25, 5,5)
matrix2 <- matrix(26:50, 5,5)
```

Suppose, I want to subset the first 3 columns of the above matrices,

```
list2env(
   setNames(
          lapply(mget(ls(pattern="matrix")), `[`, ,1:3),
                  paste("new", ls(pattern="matrix"),sep="_")), 
                                               envir=.GlobalEnv)

  new_matrix1
  #     [,1] [,2] [,3]
  #[1,]    1    6   11
  #[2,]    2    7   12
  #[3,]    3    8   13
  #[4,]    4    9   14
  #[5,]    5   10   15

  new_matrix2
  #      [,1] [,2] [,3]
  # [1,]   26   31   36
  # [2,]   27   32   37
  # [3,]   28   33   38
  # [4,]   29   34   39
  # [5,]   30   35   40
```

- `ls(pattern="matrix")` will output `[1] "matrix1" "matrix2"`
- `mget` get the values stored in the above matrices as a list
- Subset the first 3 columns of matrices in list using `lapply(...,`[`,1:3)`
- Change the name of the list elements from `matrix1`, `matrix2` by using `setNames` and `paste`
- Use `list2env` to create new objects `new_matrix1`, `new_matrix2`.  However, in your case, this would create 472 `new_matrices` in the global environment.  I would prefer to subset the matrices in a list do all the necessary calculations within the list.  Then you could use `write.table` or `write.matrix` from `library(MASS)` to write the list elements to file.

Comment: I did not see your solution and already assigned the "go" to dayne. Sorry! Thank you, it would work as well!

Answer (score 0):

If you started with a dataframe

here is how you can end with a list of matrix splitted by the groups (and having its name) and with the number of row you want:

```
library("ddply")
dlply(iris, .(Species), function(x) x[1:10,])
```

iris is a dummy dataframe you have with base R;
Species is your factor group